# Do artifacts have to upload to gitlab to be reused between stages?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to use copy some Jars in my Dockerfile after I run a `gradle` build.

highlevel, the gitlab-yml has a `build` and a `docker build` and a deploy. I don't want to upload anything to gitlab artifact server, but simply just use the temporary files to build my image and publish it elsewhere. Is this possible? I'm wondering if `artifacts` implies an upload to the gitlab servers.

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts are one way, but you can also use [`cache`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/) instead. Which one is the best option depends on your exact use case, but seems like the cache should work ok.

Alternatively, you can build the docker image, push it to the gitlab container registry, and pull it directly from there in later steps.